# Is it Helpful to transfer all media library to another host?

Tags: media-library

I want to transfer all media library including all images to a download host and my goal is the speed of loading website improve
for example my website is example.com and all images load from cdn.example.com
but I am wondering while my main host has 60 GB space and actualy I don't have problem with the space and I just want to improve the speed of website.
What do you suggest to do?!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transfer all media library to another host to improve the speed of your website. Instead, you have to follow several ways of optimizing your website. For instance, you can [optimize images of your WordPress website](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-optimize-images-for-your-wordpress-site/) for a better speed. You can use plugins, like Imsize, to reduce the size of the images. It will allow them to load at a significantly faster pace.

You can also optimize database and use an effective cache plugin.